# I get a 1570 Cocoa error because the relationship var to parent entity results nil Core Data swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to save to `CoreData`a new record but when I try I get a `1570 Cocoa error`. In the error the only things the I see nil are `user` which is the relationship `user var` to parent entity and two other attributes that are set as optional in the property inspector, so they are not required. I don't understand this because I do perform a User fetch and check to see if active logged in is the same as the fetched username, and the value is correct.. maybe there is something I'm not seeing from the error print.

This is the function:

```
static func saveBooking(bookingId: String, bookingDate: String, bookingStart: String, bookingEnd: String, customerName: String, price: String, workList: String) throws {
        let context = CoreData.databaseContext

        let request: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let fetch = try context.fetch(request)
            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@       fetching user")
            for value in fetch {
                if value.name == UserDetails.fullName {
                    print("User is: \(value.name!)")  //correct

                    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                        let booking = Booking(context: context)
                        booking.user?.name = value.name! // results nil and causes error when saving
                        booking.bookingId = bookingId
                        booking.bookingDate = bookingDate
                        booking.bookingStart = bookingStart
                        booking.bookingEnd = bookingEnd
                        booking.customerName = customerName
                        booking.bookingPrice = price
                        booking.worksList = workList

                        do {
                            try context.save()
                            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@    New booking is saved")
                        } catch  {
                            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    Error saving new booking")
                            print(error)
                        }


                    } else {
                        // Fallback on earlier versions
                        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Booking", in: context)
                        let booking = Booking(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context)
                        booking.user?.name = value.name
                         booking.bookingId = bookingId
                        booking.bookingDate = bookingDate
                        booking.bookingStart = bookingStart
                        booking.bookingEnd = bookingEnd
                        booking.customerName = customerName
                        booking.bookingPrice = price
                        booking.worksList = workList
                        do {
                            try context.save()
                            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@    New booking is saved")
                        } catch  {
                            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    Error saving new booking")
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch  {
            print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@      Error in fetching a user")
        }
    }
```

and this is the print of the error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@    Error saving new booking
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "(null)" UserInfo={NSDetailedErrors=(
    "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<Booking: 0x6000006240f0> (entity: Booking; id: 0x600002501860 <x-coredata:///Booking/t0A133AFE-B419-4941-AADC-6C9AE234A8EF2> ; data: {\n    bookingDate = 20190405;\n    bookingEnd = \"15:30\";\n    bookingId = 201904051430;\n    bookingPrice = \"45.0\";\n    bookingStart = \"14:30\";\n    customerName = \"vincenzo calia\";\n    shopLogoUrl = nil;\n    shopName = nil;\n    user = nil;\n    worksList = \"Revisione Generale, \";\n}), NSValidationErrorKey=user, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}",
    "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)\" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<Booking: 0x600000630190> (entity: Booking; id: 0x60000251b120 <x-coredata:///Booking/t0A133AFE-B419-4941-AADC-6C9AE234A8EF3> ; data: {\n    bookingDate = 20190405;\n    bookingEnd = \"18:30\";\n    bookingId = 201904051730;\n    bookingPrice = \"45.0\";\n    bookingStart = \"17:30\";\n    customerName = \"vincenzo calia\";\n    shopLogoUrl = nil;\n    shopName = nil;\n    user = nil;\n    worksList = \"Revisione Generale, \";\n}), NSValidationErrorKey=user, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}"
)}
```

can you spot where the problem is?
Many thanks as usual

Comment: Can you re-check if the user and other two attributes are actually marked as an option in the xcdatamodeld?

Comment: @JayantJaiswal `user` is the name of the relationship to the parent entity `User` and is not marked as optional, the other two `shopLogoUrl`and `shopName`are attributes of the entity `Booking`and they are marked as optional in property inspector. 
 Thing is when I print the fetched `User` name in the line `print("User is: \(value.name!)")` it prints the correct value, then I assign it to `Booking.user` and that should set the new `Booking`record as child o the fetched `User`but I instead get the nil value that throws the 1570 error. What can I try to see where the assigned value gets lost?

Comment: I actually forgot to add the booking to user's bookings and I added this line `value.addToBookings(booking)`, now it works, but still I don 't  understand  why I get nil during the properties value attribution. I now print user.name after saving to context and it's correct but if it was nil before how does it get the value? If I print it's value after `value.addToBookings(booking)`it actually has the correct value. It `value.addToBookings(booking)`sort o f validating all the values and makes them available only afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing to add the new entry to entity's parent before saving context, and obviously was throwing an error so I just added the line `value.addToBookings(booking)`and it all works as expected. I could actually avoid altogether giving a value for parent relationship as I actually add directly throug the parent's function. 
Hope this will be helping others.